# Docker Server - Change Group Name from Docker

Tags: docker

I am getting ready to deploy my docker server / private registry. I have to add all of my users to a "docker" group in order for them to access. I already have all of my users in a group called "developer" is there a way I can change this default group in docker server (perhaps in the daemon.conf file) so I don't have to assign all of my users to another group?

Comment: Since you can trivially use Docker to edit any file on the host as root, you may as well just give them `sudo` access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dockerd man page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) describes the `group` option:

```
  -G, --group string                          Group for the unix socket (default "docker")
```

You can set this in `daemon.json` by adding a `group` key:

```
{
  ...
  "group": "developer",
  ...
}
```

You will need to restart Docker for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to putting group in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` as larksks says above, on systemctl systems you must all run

```
systemctl edit docker.socket
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and in the editor add the lines

```
[Socket]
SocketGroup=developer
```

then `systemctl restart docker`